# Is there a way to see how the markup of a per-site meta answer is formed?

Tags: support, markdown, revisions-list, view-source

I sometimes see a useful markup feature in a per-site meta answer. However, I cannot edit it to see how one did it, since editing (or suggesting edits) is disabled for users with less than 2k reputation on per-site metas.

Is there a way to see the source code of a per-site meta answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More easily, if the post hasn't been edited, copy the post id contained in the URL shown by clicking on "share" below the post (the first number, e.g. for this answer that is `273594`) and go to the URL formed as below:

```
meta.stackexchange.com/posts/273594/revisions
```

Then click on "[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/52ed818f-ec00-475a-bcc7-3b0c96048d02/view-source)".

Otherwise, if the post has been edited, just click on the "edited [...]" link below the post and switch to the "side-by-side markdown" view of a revision containing it (if that happens to be the first revision you'll still have to click on "source").

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the question or answer is posted before last Monday 03:00 UTC, when [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) updates.

You can find the raw markup in the `text` column of the `posthistory` table.

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/427220?postid=303865&opt.textResults=true) gives you all the body revisions for a specific post.

```sql
select text
from posthistory 
where postid = ##postid:int?303865##
and posthistorytypeid in (2,5) -- body
```

I find it easiest to use the textresult here. Remember to switch the site to the one you're interested in...

Answer (score 4):

There a real-time option you can use.

First, you need to know the post ID. It is in the url, like this one:

```
http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/
```

You take that ID (2184 in this case), and use that to open the revisions page:

```
http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/posts/2184/revisions
```

There you can click *source* to get the source of the post.