# Copy question or answer source text when "Suggested edit queue is full"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, suggested-edits, view-source

For users below 2k reputation who need to copy a question or answer source text, the only option nowadays is to use the "edit" button and copy the source from the edit page. When the "Suggested edit queue is full", this is not possible.

- Is there another way to copy the source text of a question or answer? What about comments?
- Would it be useful to add a "view source" button to questions and answers? What about comments?

Comment: Noteworthy this only happens for users below 2k.

Comment: Is it a common issue for the edits queue to be full on some sites? My experience is it is very rare as more users can review edits (2K) so couldn't you just wait a minuet for a space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to see how the markup of a per-site meta answer is formed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273592/is-there-a-way-to-see-how-the-markup-of-a-per-site-meta-answer-is-formed) (This question asks how to view the page source without opening the edit tool because suggested edits are disabled on per-site metas, and the accepted answer shows how to access the page's source)